# VERY SLOW - Databinding update UI from fragment

Tags: android, android-databinding

Apparently there is a science to databainding in android of which I clearly dont get. I keep ending up fighting updating views via the fragment or viewmodel where some things "just work" others are seemingly nonfunctional.

I want to disable a login button, change its text and set an alpha after its been clicked until I get an API response then I change it back. As you can imagine, I dont want the user submitting an auth request repeatedly. Pre-databinding the fragment would handle the onClick() listener and I would either use butterknife to bind the element or manually do so with findViewById(). Either way when I changed the view it was practically instant. Now with databinding, it seems haphazard and in some cases very slow while others seem instant. Im not including the code that will change it back since its not changing the view in the first place.

While writing this I had the same issue over and over, the button never changes. The observer in the fragment gets called (In the log it shows in the order I expect it to have been called) but the UI just doesnt update. I ran it on an emulator again and oddly the observer log doesnt appear until much later and then the view updated as expected, sorta. It didnt update when I clicked on the button but at least the button changed before the API response came back. Not that this was helpful because the time between the click and the ui change the button can still be rapidly clicked. I stopped the app and re-ran it and im back to the original issue, its not updating at all. No code change was made between the tests.

Im using SingleLiveEvent unmodified from googles architecture samples
https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

activity_main_login <-- its a fragment not activity but I havent refactored it yet.
This is truncated so it might not work without a layout container.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainViewModel"
            type="com.example.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
    </data>
    ...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> mainViewModel.loginClicked()}"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#e05206"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fingerprintSwitch"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="101dp" />
    ....
</layout>
```

MainFragment

```
ActivityMainLoginBinding binding;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "-> onCreateView()" );
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

    getLifecycle().addObserver(mainViewModel);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.activity_main_login, container, false);
    mView = binding.getRoot();
    binding.setMainViewModel(mainViewModel);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this); // Yeah this is what I forgot last time...

    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppLog.d(TAG, "-> onViewCreated()" );
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mainViewModel.getShowLoading().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), showLoading -> {
        AppLog.d(TAG, "showLoading changed");
        this.loading = true;

        binding.btnLogin.setText(R.string.loggingIn);
        binding.btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
        binding.btnLogin.setAlpha(.5f);
    });
}
```

MainViewModel

```
private SingleLiveEvent<Boolean> showLoading = new SingleLiveEvent<>();

public void loginClicked() {
    Log.d(TAG, "loginClicked()");
    showLoading.setValue(true);
    login();
}
```

Here is what the logs look like when it runs and you click the login button...

```
D/MainViewModel: loginClicked()
D/MainFragment: showLoading changed
D/MainViewModel: login()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I included the Retrofit2 code that made/received the API call but it had to do with the threading. I wrapped the method that called the synchronous retrofit resource in

```
new Handler().post(() -> { });
```

So login() looks more like this now

```
private void login() {
    new Handler().post(() -> {
        // original retrofit call
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> authResponse = restApi.doAuthSync());
        t.start();

        // Joining thread so we wait for the response
        // I believe this to be the actual culprit of the problem
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        // handle authResponse
        ...
    });
}
```

Even though the API call itself must be done on its own thread (and was) the entire thing just held up the UI thread most likely due to the thread.join(). That caused the Databindings not to update. This may have been resolved using RxJava but I haven't implemented that yet and for a simple task its not necessary.